# Scatter overlay on image with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an RGB image, img, and I want to produce a new image, img2, with an overlay scatter plot on it.

If X Y Z are respectively the nx1 vectors of x-coord, y-coord and "magnitude" value of my scatter what I'm doing is:

```
imshow(img);
hold on;
scatter(X,Y,3,Z,'fill');
hold off;
```

In this way I actually get an image with the scatter plotted, but the problem is that every point of the scatter has the same color (blu) instead of what normally happens when I use

```
figure;
scatter(X,Y,3,Z,'fill');
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `figure;` before `imshow()`, which will enables you to draw on the image with the color that what normally it should be.

```
figure; % add this line before imshow()
imshow(img);
hold on;
scatter(X,Y,3,Z,'fill');
hold off;
```

Here is an example I just tested:

```
figure; % add this line before imshow()
imshow(img);
hold on;

load seamount
s = sqrt(-z/2);
c = z;
scatter(x,y,s,c,'fill')

hold off;
```

[image]

You can see that its color shown on the image is (roughly) consistent with the color when drawing it alone.

[image]

---

**Edit**: you can always change the color to whatever you like by setting `scatter`'s color properties, i.e. `MarkerEdgeColor` and `MarkerFaceColor`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't work for me, can't figure out why.

Comment: I tried with different data and it worked actually. So I guess your answer is ok.
I can't still understand why it doesn't work in any situation, thanks anyway.

Comment: @mbPro You can always change the color to whatever you like by setting `scatter`'s color properties, i.e. `MarkerEdgeColor` and `MarkerFaceColor`.

Comment: Ok I finally found the problem, but not the solution. The range of color in the img is from 0 to 255, but the vector Z of "magnitude" in my case ranges from -0.3 to 0.3. So when the scatter is overlayed to the img the Z values are treated as they were in the range 0-255 and so, every point is plotted as blu.

Comment: @mbPro I see. Glad to hear you made it.

Comment: Ok, remapping the values of Z to 0-255 it works fine. Here is my function to do that:
 `function [ Aremaped ] = remap( A,lnew,hnew )
Aremaped = zeros(size(A));
lold=min(A);
hold=max(A);
for i=1:length(A)
    newVal = lnew + (A(i)-lold)*(hnew-lnew)/(hold-lold);
    Aremaped(i) = newVal
end

end`
hope this can help

Comment: @mbPro You can add these to your question or even as an answer to this question and let others can learn from. Good work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, remapping the values of Z to 0-255 it works fine. Here is my function to do that:

```
function [ Aremaped ] = remap( A,lnew,hnew )
 Aremaped = zeros(size(A));
 lold=min(A);
 hold=max(A);
 for i=1:length(A)
     newVal = lnew + (A(i)-lold)*(hnew-lnew)/(hold-lold);
     Aremaped(i) = newVal 
 end
end
```

Hope this can help